# Can't select page layout when creating a new page in Rails alchemy-cms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, alchemy-cms

I'm new to [alchemy-cms](http://alchemy-cms.com/about).

I created a fresh install from the [guides](http://guides.alchemy-cms.com/edge/getting_started.html). I did not add any *[concept or structure](http://guides.alchemy-cms.com/2.9/best_practice_create_blog_template.html)*. 
Going to localhost:3000 I have to add the first user and after that I have a clean site.

When trying to add a new page, I have to select a type (page-layout?) and type in a name.
[image: window of creating a new subpage in Alchemy]

The *Type* combobox remains empty, and therefore the website don't allow me to add a page. What am I doing wrong? I think I'm missing something very obvious here.

I have looked allready in the source code, and running the following:

```
rails console
Alchemy::PageLayout.all
```

and this results in:

```
=> [{"name"=>"index", "unique"=>true, "elements"=>["article"], "autogenerate"=>["article"]}]
```

So I would guess the combobox should be filled with this item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `index` page layout is marked as `unique`, so it can only be added once per language. And as the so called language root page (the first most page in your page tree) already has this page layout, no new page can be created using this page layout.

In order to fix your problem you need to add another page layout to your `page_layouts.yml` file. It is good practice to add an `standard` page layout that is not unique (default) and can therefore be added multiple times per language.